# Video with z-index: -1 is breaking fixed div with z-index:1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is an odd one. I have a fixed nav bar to the top of the page with

```
           .headerbar {
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 110;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background:#FFF;
              }
```

I also have a html5 video on the page acting as a background video for a div its css is the following

```
       video {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            z-index: -1;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

The issue is that when I scroll the page my fixed header moves about 15px and then wont move, but If I give the video a positive z-index everything works fine although the video is not a background then.

This is very strange I have never come across this, any ideas ? anyone ?

Comment: can you post  a jsfiddle?

Comment: I suggest also including your HTML, and if possible a working example of the problem. And fix your formatting on your code blocks, it hurts my eyes